# hiding button, then waiting 2 seconds before showing it again, after clicking the button

Tags: java, button, sleep, event-dispatch-thread

I have this school project I'm making, where I need to make my code hide a button, and then sleep, and then continue, but it never hides the button.

I have one class which is started by a button press, it then starts another method which should hide the button, and then it starts a method in another class which does a bunch of things which it does perfectly, and then it starts a 3rd method in a 3rd class, where the first thing it should do is sleep, but it sleeps before hiding my button, and totally skips hiding my button.

Here is the codes part (don't mind the danish value/method names):

```
public void turncard(final int navn,boolean spiller){
    knap.setVisible(false);
    EqualCheck.storevalue(this,spiller);
}
```

i know this part is surrounded by a if.. but it does get called like this.

```
if(spiller){                   //tester om det er spilleren der har vendt kort,
   kort.repaint();             //og hvis det er, så starter den computerens
   Main.spillet.computertur(); //tur.
}
```

and then at the start of the "computertur" method

```
public void computertur() {
    for(int i = 0; i < kortene.size(); i++) {
        kortene.get(i).knap.setEnabled(false);
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch ( Exception e) {
        System.out.println("sleep failed.");
    }
```

I did read about the `invokeAndWait` command which should be better for EDT:s, but how can I use it to pause `mythread`... or even, a better question, why doesn't it hide the button? :) I mean, in my head calling the `setVisible(false)` before anything else will hide it before it does anything else.. Why doesn't it?

Comment: Shouldn't your last example code be calling setVisible(false) instead of setEnabled(false)? setEnable simply disables the button making unclickable, it doesn't hide it.

Comment: the set enable is to make it so that the user cannot click the buttons while it executes cumputertur(), in the end it undoes the setEnable(false) .. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never invoke Thread.sleep(...) while executing code on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). This will freeze the GUI and prevent it from repainting iteself.

In general your code needs to execute on a separate Thread, except for the code that sets the button invisble. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and solutions.

Comment: the invokeAndWait() is usefull, but i just cant see how i can use it in my case as it needs to do things after it have hidden my button ..

Comment: You should probably not be using invokeAndWait(). You should be creating a new Thread to run your task. When the thread starts you use invokeLater(...) to disable the button. The you use Thread.sleep(). Then you use invokeLater to enable the button.